# babel-loader npm issue: no longer builds and pushed to Heroku without changes made

Tags: node.js, babel-loader

I have an app that I was able to push to Heroku on multiple occasions with no issues.
However, after making simple UI fixes I now get an error (npm ERR! While resolving: babel-loader@7.1.1) when uploading to Heroku.
I have not installed any new packages nor have I updated any since I last pushed to Heroku, so I'm not sure why it would be a problem now.

Here is the full error:

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: babel-loader@7.1.1
remote:        npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.68.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
remote:        npm ERR!   webpack@"^5.68.0" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!   peer webpack@"4.x.x || 5.x.x" from @webpack-cli/configtest@1.1.1
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@webpack-cli/configtest
remote:        npm ERR!     @webpack-cli/configtest@"^1.1.1" from webpack-cli@4.9.2
remote:        npm ERR!     node_modules/webpack-cli
remote:        npm ERR!       webpack-cli@"^4.9.2" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!       3 more (@webpack-cli/configtest, @webpack-cli/info, @webpack-cli/serve)
remote:        npm ERR!   7 more (css-loader, file-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin, ...)
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
remote:        npm ERR! peer webpack@"2 || 3" from babel-loader@7.1.1
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/babel-loader
remote:        npm ERR!   babel-loader@"7.1.1" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@3.12.0
remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
remote:        npm ERR!   peer webpack@"2 || 3" from babel-loader@7.1.1
remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
remote:        npm ERR!     babel-loader@"7.1.1" from the root project
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
remote:        npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
remote:        npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! For a full report see:
remote:        npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.Nvb5b/_logs/2023-06-05T18_34_48_333Z-eresolve-report.txt
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Nvb5b/_logs/2023-06-05T18_34_48_333Z-debug-0.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

I tried:

- installing all modules again from lock file just in case something broke
- removed lock file and updated everything (that broke everything though)

I added my lock file back and reinstalled with all the versions I originally had for my dependencies and its running like it did before I troubleshooted (on dev environment).
I'm back at square one. I have my code working just fine on dev environment so not sure what the issue is.
If it helps, here is my webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'){
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.test'})
}else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.development'})
}

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProd = env === 'production'
  
  return{
    entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/app.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s[ca]ss)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
     },
    plugins:[
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename:'styles.css'
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID),
        'process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID)
      })
    ],
    devtool: isProd ? 'source-map' :'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '/dist'
    }
  }
}
```